# Accidentally clicked "Turn off messages about file history". How do I turn them back on?

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 I clicked a notification and it opened up Control Panel to: `Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance` and there was a message about file history saying something about the fact that I had removed my file history drive.

I accidentally clicked the "Turn off messages about file history" link thing and then it instantly disappeared, but I actually want to have notifications about file history.

I can't find the setting to turn this back on. Please help if you know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel (icon view)>Security and Maintenance

When that window opens look on the left side for "Change Security and Maintenance Settings"

When that window opens tick the File History Box.

[image]

[image]